# ServiceStack.Funq.Quartz cannot instantiating type?

Tags: servicestack, quartz.net, funq

ServiceStack.Funq.Quartz Sample Code is

```
public class MyServices : Service
{
    public object Any(Hello request)
    {
        return new HelloResponse { Result = "Hello, {0}!".Fmt(request.Name) };
    }
}

public class HelloJob : IJob
{
    private MyServices MyServices { get; set; }
    public HelloJob(MyServices myServices)
    {
        MyServices = myServices;
    }
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        var response = MyServices.Any(new ServiceModel.Hello
        {
            Name = "CodeRevver"
        });
        response.PrintDump();
    }
}
```

The above is works fine. if I in the MyServices Class, removed the Any function, and comment the **Execute** inner code.

```
public class MyServices : Service
{

}
```

the quartz.net will get the error:

```
[Quartz.Core.ErrorLogger】 An error occurred instantiating job to be executed. job= 'JobGroup1.GetUserJob111' Problem instantiating type 'ServiceStackWithQuartz.HelloJob'
```

why the class must have public object `Any(Hello request)` function ?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for using the package – I had no idea that other people would find it useful.

So If I understand correctly, in your situation you have:

```
public class MyServices : Service
{
}
```

And you’re trying to resolve this Service via constructor injection, which is effectively doing a:

```
container.Resolve<MyServices>();
```

This will fail because of the way the ServiceStack Funq IoC works. You can’t resolve a ServiceStack Service that has nothing in it (you'd probably never want to either) – It has to at least have one service implementation, It doesn’t matter what the implementation is.

Also, if you want to improve ServiceStack.Funq.Quartz, feel free to contribute to the code base.

**Edit:**  It's probably worth mentioning that you can inject a "Non-Service" class with your logic in it if you want. You can resolve other classes that aren't based off of ServiceStack.Service even if there's nothing in them.

**Edit 2:**  Responding to your "Service wont dispose" problem.  This is the same across ServiceStack and has nothing to do with your Quartz Job.  If you call a:

```
container.Resolve<MyServices>().Any(new new ServiceModel.Hello { });
```

from AppHost for example, your service **wont dispose** by itself.  If you want it to dispose you can wrap it in a using statement.  e.g.

```
using (var service = MyServices)
{
    var response = MyServices.Any(new ServiceModel.Hello { });
}
```

The **using** will ensure that your service will be disposed afterwards.

**Alternatively** you can add the interface "IDispose" on to your Quartz Job and implement a Dispose() method that will do a:

```
MyServices.Dispose();
```

This will be called after a job has executed.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, you are right. because of the way the ServiceStack Funq IoC ,  It has to at least have one service implementation, the one service if contains (any,put,get,post..),  resolve works fine , but I only need some database operations,   @mythz  has any advice?

Comment: Funq uses `container.Resolve<T>` for constructor injection which represents a mandatory dependency, but if you use **public properties** Funq instead resolves dependencies with `container.TryResolve<T>` which can be optional.

Comment: At last, I have to in the initialize class add `container.RegisterAutoWiredType(typeof(MyServices));` .  but I found the Quartz.net Job Executed, It will not Invoke the `Service.Dispose()` , then If in MyService I  Invoke Db Operation, It will not close the connection and  dispose(). @Michael Clark